# The synchronicity of for...await loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to visualize the synchronicity of `for...await` loops in JavaScript.

It appears that in an `async` generator function **both** `yield` and `await` will stop progress and cue up a continuation on a microtask.

In other words: yielding is *always* asynchronous in this context, **even if you don't use the `await` keyword**.

Is this correct? What about `async` generator functions outside of the context of `for...await` loops?

Below a tight microtask loop is created using `then`, in an attempt to see how tasks are interleaved.

```js
function printNums() {
    let counter = 0
    function go() {
        console.log(counter++)    
        if(counter < 10) Promise.resolve().then(go)
    }
    Promise.resolve().then(go)
}

printNums()

async function asyncFn() {
    console.log('inside asyncFn 1')
    await null
    console.log('inside asyncFn 2')
}

asyncFn()

const asyncIterable = {
    async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        console.log('inside asyncIterable 1')
        yield '⛱'
        console.log('inside asyncIterable 2')
        await null
        console.log('inside asyncIterable 3')
        yield ''
        yield ''
    }
}

async function printAsyncIterable() {
    for await(let z of asyncIterable) {
        console.log(z)
    }
}
printAsyncIterable()
```

Comment: Correct, but as you know, you should limit a question to *one* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words: yielding is always asynchronous in this context, even if you don't use the `await` keyword

Yes. Inside an asynchronous generator function, the expression

```
yield value
```

behaves as if you had written

```
await (yield (await value))
```

You cannot yield promises, and you cannot receive promises, they always get automatically unwrapped by the `next()` call.

Comment: OK so progress is blocked on `yield new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res('a'), 1000))`, and the resolved result is passed along. Also: I presume `yield await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res('a'), 1000))` is valid grammar, it's just that `for...await` loops unwrap it. Another consumer of the function might do something different?

Comment: No, this is the same for all consumers, it's the async generator itself that does the unwrapping not the `for await … of` loop. `yield await` is valid syntax, but pointless.

Comment: See https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/93 and https://github.com/tc39/notes/blob/main/meetings/2017-05/may-25.md#15iva-revisiting-async-generator-yield-behavior for discussion of this behaviour