# How to throw an error in an async generator function

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, error-handling, yield

Within an async generator function in Javascript, which is intended as a transform function, the first parameter is itself an async generator function.
Within the function there is a conversion and a check. If the check is falsy, the generator function should be aborted. If the check is correct, the result should be yielded. I have simulated the error with the random.

I have found three ways to throw the error:

- return Promise.reject(new Error("Some Message"));
- throw new Error("Some Message.");
- yield Promise.reject(new Error("Some Message"));

```ts
export async function* transformAsync<T>(
    source: AsyncGenerator<T, void, unknown>,
) {
    for await (const line of source) {

        const transformedLine = transformWithSomeMagic(line);

        if(Math.random() > 0.8) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("Some Message"));
            // OR
            throw new Error("Some Message.");
            // OR
            yield Promise.reject(new Error("Some Message"));
        }

        yield transformedLine;
    }
}
```

The results are identical for all. I wonder where the difference is and if there are leaks when using streams as the source parameter, because they are compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter wether you `throw` or `return` in a `for..of` loop, the iterator will be closed (no matter wether it is sync or async) [[spec]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset).

Conceptually, the result of a further execution of an async generator is represented as a Promise, returning and yielding is like a resolution, and throwing is like a rejection. Now resolving a Promise with another Promise will "flatten" it, therefore the `Promise.reject` wrappers are superfluous. [[spec]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-asyncgeneratorresumenext)

```
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Some Message"));
        // barely equals
        resolve(Promise.reject(new Error("Some Message"))

        throw new Error("Some Message.");
        // barely equals
        reject(new Error("Some Message."));

        yield Promise.reject(new Error("Some Message"));
        // this one's more complicated, but it also barely equals
        resolve(Promise.reject(new Error("Some Message")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are all identical. There are no leaks, all of them also close the `source` iterator (calling `.return()` on it).

You should use the simple `throw new Error(…);` for explicitly throwing an error yourself, the other forms are useful when you are calling a promise-returning function and [work as with an implicit `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62395994/1048572).