# Is "yield await" redundant in JavaScript async generator functions?

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, yield

Promises yielded within `async function*` declarations seem to be automatically awaited before the iterator result is sent to the caller ([source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function*#description)). Does this mean that `yield await somePromise` is redundant and `yield somePromise` will produce the same behavior in all cases? Or, are there exceptions to watch out for?

P.S. I thought there might be some behavioral differences related to error handling contexts and `try/catch`. From my experimentation though, it seems that a promise yielded in a `try` block will always be caught and handled *within* the async generator, regardless if there is an explicit `await`.

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60367122/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await` is quite redundant here. Using `await` also delays the resolve timing in the microtask queue.

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log(1))
  .then(() => console.log(2))
  .then(() => console.log(3))
  .then(() => console.log(4))
  .then(() => console.log(5));
  
(async () => {
  const func = async function*() {
    yield await Promise.resolve('yield await');
  };
  
  for await (let i of func()) {
      console.log(i);
  }
})();
```

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log(1))
  .then(() => console.log(2))
  .then(() => console.log(3))
  .then(() => console.log(4))
  .then(() => console.log(5));
  
(async () => {
  const func = async function*() {
    yield Promise.resolve('yield');
  };
  
  for await (let i of func()) {
      console.log(i);
  }
})();
```